# How do I get free ports in the specific range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, port, ubuntu-16.04

I can use python to get free ports, but I want to get a specific range of free ports.

I try to get it using a while loop, but I can't get the vaule I wanted, maybe take a long time

```
import socket

SO_BINDTODEVICE=25

def get_free_port(iface=None):
    s = socket.socket()

    if iface:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, bytes(iface,'utf8'))

    s.bind(('',0))
    port = 0
    while(port<60100 or port>60300):
        ip = s.getsockname()[0]
        port = s.getsockname()[1]
    s.close()

    return ip,port


print(get_free_port())
```

I hope to get the port I want in a short time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def next_free_port( port=1024, max_port=65535 ):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while port <= max_port:
        try:
            sock.bind(('', port))
            sock.close()
            return port
        except OSError:
            port += 1
    raise IOError('no free ports')
```